# selenium Webdriver wait until expected conditon not working properly on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-ec2, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I made a script to visit a page and log in then get a download link from the page.
The script works fine on my local window machine, but it's not working on Amazon EC2 instance(ubuntu)
The code is as below

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

dir_chrome_driver = "c:/selenium/driver/chromedriver.exe"
parser = ConfigParser()
option = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()

url = "https://ams.amazon.com/webpublisher/analytics/requested_downloads"

option.add_argument('--user-agent="Chrome/102.0.5005.115"')
option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=dir_chrome_driver, options=option)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option)
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ap_email')))

driver.find_element(By.ID, "ap_email").send_keys(USER_ID)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "ap_password").send_keys(USER_PASSWORD)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "signInSubmit").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.download-link')))
download_link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".download-link")
```

It gives me an error 
"File "aps.py", line 46, in <module>
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.download-link')))
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 90, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:"
I added fixed time wait between 'click' and WebDriverWait like below.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "signInSubmit").click()

time.sleep(30)

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.download-link')))
```

It worked for a while, but it became not work again today.
I tried to change wait time but the driver still in the login page.

Please advise me if there is any possible cause or solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different setup for selenium on ubuntu/debian:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: It works perfect. I didn't realize that service is the problem since I already tried passing "Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()". Thank you.